# aws cli で配列と配列でない値をくっつけて１行で表示したい

Tags: aws-cli

例えば EC2 一覧のインスタンスIDとタグ名一覧をインスタンスごとに１行ずつ表示したい時

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId, Tags[].Value]'
```

とかいてしまうと

```
[
    [
        "i-xxxxxxxxxx",
        [
            "tag1",
            "tag2",
            "tag3"
        ]
    ],
      :
]
```

となってしまい --output text をつけても別の行で表示されてしまいます

```
[
   ["i-xxxxxxxxxx", "tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
      :
],
```

という形にするような --query の書き方はありますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`map`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#map)を使うのはどうでしょうか？

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
  --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId, Tags[].Value] | map(&[], @)'
```